# Order of Calls on performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

When I call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` I am overriding `prepareForSegue:` afterwards in order to set some properties on my destination view controller. However, I'm trying to understand the order of operations here to make sure it's safe.

I instantiate the destination view controller with:

```
MyViewController *myVC = (MyViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
```

Afterwards I set a few properties on it - namely, I initialize the creation of another object which handles loading different web views, and then set properties on that object:

```
[myVC setFormHandler:
    [[WebFormHandler alloc] initWithSelectedFormName:[self theFormName]]];
```

In `viewDidLoad:` of my destination controller, I then query the properties on this object, and use this to load the correct web view. Now, I am slightly confused by which happens first - the setting of the properties, or `viewDidLoad:` on the destination controller. Can it be said for certain that the properties of the view controller will always be set from `prepareForSegue:` before the `viewDidLoad:` is called?

Comment: I think this SO post answers your question

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854475/1452351

Comment: Interesting. So it seems prepareForSegue is always called first, and THEN viewDidLoad. That seems rather weird to me considering the view controller is instantiated inside the prepare method.

Comment: The viewDidLoad is not tied to the instantion but the view showing on screen.  Additionally you did not instantiate the view controller you just got a reference to an already existing object that was created by the framework or the parent controler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may have found your answer from that other post, but I just wanted to add one point of clarification.

The standard flow is

performSegue -> prepare -> loadView (in destination controller)

However, in popover segues, the destination view is loaded prior to the prepareForSegue call.

**NOTE**: This is no longer the case in iOS 8. In iOS 8, popover segue's views are NOT loaded by the time prepareForSegue is called.

Comment: Interesting about the popover segues. So then the correct method I'm assuming would be to override setters to update the destination view controller when setting properties in the prepareForSegue.. seems like a hassle!

Comment: Typically you wouldn't want to be updating view pieces in that prepare segue, but you could set properties that would then be used in that destination vc when it's view was actually loading. Alternately, you could set your source vc as the delegate for the destination, and then in the destination's load view, it could ask the delegate for data.

Comment: The point that @bgoers is making is that the destination view controller in a popover segue goes through all of its set up before the source's `prepareForSegue:sender:` is called. I'm dealing with this right now, and it is a huge hassle, and unnecessarily different from other segues.

Comment: Exactly what @SteveMadsen is saying is what I was struggling with. I ended up with a different implementation, but I believe overriding setters on pertinent properties, and from the setters then updating the view, would be a workable solution. Untested though.. just weird it would go through view loading before `prepareForSegue` is called

Comment: Hey guys, just wanted to update you, since this has changed in iOS 8. The popover segue no longer appears to be loaded before prepareForSegue as of this version.

Comment: This is incorrect - in ios8 it seems the popover view is still loaded before the prepareForSegue