# Passing String From one View Controller and Displaying it in UITextView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried every thing I could do to solve the problem because I am newbie I am not getting the clear answer.
I have two view controllers. I passed the data of textview to 2nd controller and displaying it in UILabel and there is no problem with it. But now I have to send the the text of label again to the same textview for editing. The problem is when I double tap on label it navigates me to the 1st View but does not displaying the text in textview.

```
-(void)AddTextToCanvasWithGesture:(UITextView*)takenText
{

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(35, 60,takenText.contentSize.width,takenText.contentSize.height);

    UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

    rect.origin.x=0;
    rect.origin.y=0;
    UILabel *textLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rect];


    [textLabel setText:takenText.text];
     self.text=takenText.text;

    [textLabel setTextColor:takenText.textColor];
    [textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:takenText.font.fontName size:takenText.font.pointSize]];
    [textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [textLabel sizeToFit];
    [holderView setTag:1];
    [textLabel setTag:1+1];
    [holderView addSubview:textLabel];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];

    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];

    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];



    tapRecognizer = nil;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LaunchText)];

    [doubleTapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [doubleTapRecognizer setDelegate:self];


    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
    holderView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;


    [tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer]; 

}
```

I have to send this label's text to textview of 2ndview controller

```
-(void) LaunchText{

    [self update:self.text];
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"textAdd" sender:self]; 
}

-(void)update:(NSString*)string{

    TextAddViewController *txt=[[TextAddViewController alloc]init];

    txt.usingText.text=string;
}
```

and i am fetching this string in 2nd view as

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ViewController *vm=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    self.usingText.text=vm.text;
}
```

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LaunchText)];
    
 [doubleTapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
 [doubleTapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
 [holderView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
    holderView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

Comment: -(void) LaunchText{
    


    
    TextAddViewController *txt=[[TextAddViewController alloc]init];
    
    txt.usingText.text=self.text;
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"textAdd" sender:self];
    
}

Comment: This is what i am doing on double tapping

Comment: Your second ViewController is TextAddViewController?

Comment: @user3763512 add your code in your post for everyone to understand it and fix your issue. Also as your passing the value from one to another, so you could do same or even got for delegate method.

Comment: yes It is textAssviewController

Answer (score 1):

Override below method in your `SecondViewController`, And pass `UILabel` values to `FirstViewController`.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue is called");
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CONTROLLER_SEGUE"])  {

        TextAddViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc.usgingText setText:@"SOME TEXT"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant do this because i am using  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"textAdd" sender:self]; for rest of my projet

Comment: @user3763512: You need to override above method to pass data, and about the method calling confusion. Please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059143/order-of-calls-on-performseguewithidentifier

Comment: How can i call prepareForSegue at tapGestureRecognizer? Because I did it before and throws an exception.

Comment: It's a delegate method you don't need to call it. It will call itself. Just write it in your SecondViewController. If you need to check it is calling or not? Write `NSLog` in that method or place debug pointer to method.

Comment: I mean UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LaunchText)]; here @selector is using Launch method, so id i need to call prepareForSegue Here how to write? If I am writing exception occurs

Comment: You'r not getting me, what ever you do is correct. call `LaunchText` from `@selector`. Do not need to change anything in that method. when `performSegueWithIdentifier` is called from the `LuanchText` method, `prepareForSegue` will call itself. You don't need to call any means. It is a delegate method. e.g when ever you `reloadData` of `UITableView` all other delegate method of `UITableView` are called, we do not need to call from code. Are you getting me if still confuse let me know.

Comment: Now I got Your point :) Thank you so much for clearing my concept.

Answer (score 0):

ViewController containing the textView needs a line of code in its view did Load method. 
textView . text = where ever the text came from. 
Posting more codes will help you better.