# In prepareforsegue how datas are passed by using arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

In storyboard I want to pass the datas from one viewcontroller to another but only the properties are shared but how can i share the datas by using the arguments(method).In below I have tried like this

Tableview didselect Method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ASEventDetail" sender:self];
}
```

In prepare for segue I pass the argument value in method "`[vc loadDict:[eventArr objectAtIndex:0]]`"

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ASEventDetail"]){
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        ASEventDetail *vc = [segue destinationViewController];        
        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc loadDict:[eventArr objectAtIndex:self.view.tag]];
    }
}
```

Could you please any one help me to pass the datas from one to another using methods from storyboard.

Comment: I suppose `loadDict` is your own method? What's the problem here? You could also pass the data in via properties on the destination view controller.

Comment: loadDict is my own method,my problem is while passing the data's through properties is not a problem, but here i want to ass the datas through method.I cant able to pass the datas because first my method is called and then the viewdidload is called thats my problem

Comment: Don't know if I understood your problem, but if you are using popover have a look at one one my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838160/prepareforsegue-is-not-called-after-performseguewithidentifier-with-popover-st

Comment: s you are correct thats my problem @Leonard could you help me find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data in via properties or methods (as long as that method is storing the data). However, you shouldn't be updating the UI in your `loadDict` method.

Instead, save your data in a property or instance variable, then in `viewWillAppear` on the destination controller, update the UI based on the data.

Answer (score 1):

Set your custom properties on the destination view controller,Use this method to pass the property in all of your view controllers

```
 ASEventDetail *vc = [segue destinationViewController]; 
vc.someobject=[eventArr objectAtIndex:self.view.tag];
```

for reference you can refer  [Pass Data Between View Controllers](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)