# When trying to segue, nothing happens

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have an app I am working on, and I am trying to have the logo on for a bit longer, and fade out/slide out/effect when it's done.

Here's my setup:
[image: Setup]

The Tab Bar controller is not letting me place an Image View inside it, so I created a view to have it on.

I am trying to have the logo stay on for a bit, fade out, then automatically switch the view (Segue) to the Tab Bar controller.

This is what I get out of it: http://youtu.be/l4jL0BfpR2k

So here's my code:

```
//
//  BDNLogoViewController.m
//  Bronydom Network
//
//  Created by name on 10/1/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 name. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BDNLogoViewController.h"
#import "BDNTabBarController.h"
#import "BDNFirstViewController.h"

@interface BDNLogoViewController ()

@end

@implementation BDNLogoViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        _imageview.alpha = 0;
    }];

    //BDNTabBarController *viewController = [[BDNTabBarController alloc] init];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    (void)@selector(seguePerform:);

}

- (void)seguePerform:(id)sender
{
    //BDNTabBarController *myNewVC = [[BDNTabBarController alloc] init];

    // do any setup you need for myNewVC

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"open" sender:sender];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Yes, "open" is defined as the segue id.

Do you guys have any ideas on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix, add this

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"open" sender:self];
}
```

Remove this from your code

> (void)@selector(seguePerform:);
>   // and all other unnecessary segue stuff you had

Comment: The first image disappeared because I am animating the Alpha of the image. Oh, I tried to log at the prepareForSegue part, but I never got the message. Have any more ideas?

Comment: Apparently the "prepareforSegue" method is not being called or the Segue `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"open" sender:sender];` isn't working.

Comment: It looks like I have the correct one (Main), I also do have the "open" in the Segue Identifier box.

Comment: upload code to dropbox or something and i'll have a look, could also put a log in the viewDidLoad of the destination VC. also have a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838160/prepareforsegue-is-not-called-after-performseguewithidentifier-with-popover-st

Comment: Okay. Source posted: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9sp5g3x6qtnwsz/Bronydom%20Network.zip

Comment: Works for me.. i had to delete the "Tune in.png" reference as it was missing - but works 100%.

Comment: Try setting the logo view to default. The app loads perfectly with it set to load the Tab Bar controller directly.

Comment: Got it to try and segue, and getting this error Bronydom Network[72725:a0b] Warning: Attempt to present <UITabBarController: 0xa561100> on <BDNLogoViewController: 0xa555150> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: after some research found an answer. glad to help